# Strange artifacts in render (in viewport render not showing)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, artifacts

I have a huge problem. I have an object with some holes. In viewport render there's all good, but when I render a frame, there're some artifacts.
I tried fix the mesh by shading smooth/flat, recalculate normals, set normals from faces and nothing work. My mesh was imported from .STEP but I connected faces.

CYCLES, Blender 3.0

Someone could help me?

Best regards

BLEND FILE: https://we.tl/t-08ebCxzBan

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file.

Comment: I've just provided blend file

Comment: my guess is that this is caused by your topology and using booleans, you used 1 big plane and cut all those holes in it right? Boolean don't work that easily as especially they can create these lines (why? Because your topology is a bunch of n-gons with non uniform scale, it simply doesn't work at all) what you need is to either use low poly booleans and clean it manually or clean this mess manually (I tried to fix it with better topology but personally I would suggest to go back before you applied bool, subdivide that plane into smaller grid and the try to apply it

Comment: @MikoCG unfortunately I modeled it and did not cut it out. I got the finished model in .STEP and used the conversion to .STL mesh. So it is not necessary to undo the breakdown at the moment, I need something to do in the mesh

Comment: i had no problems rendering it out at 3.2 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kgy4.png but same on 3.0 ...so i would suggest using 3.1 or 3.2 if possible. You should file a bug report....[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/stKBB.png

Comment: @Chris Thanks so much! I've downloaded 3.2 version and it was fixed :)

Comment: You are welcome